# id value is null when I use mongodb and typeorm

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, typeorm

I try to use typeorm to create an entity that named Post. like this:

```js
import { Column, Entity, ObjectId, ObjectIdColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class Post {
  @ObjectIdColumn()
  id: ObjectId;

  @Column('text')
  title: string;

  @Column('text')
  content: string;

  @Column({type:'boolean', default:true})
  active = true
}
```

but when I insert a new record to this table, the data looks like this:

```js
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "649d3e07bfbabc4932b792d3"
  },
  "id": null,
  "title": "salam",
  "content": "in yek test ast",
  "active": true
}
```

id field is null, and finally when I try to call "findByOne({id})", I dont find any record!!!

Comment: How did you insert the record?

Comment: through create a model and bind a value to the instanse without any value for id

Answer (score 0):

Please change this line

```
@ObjectIdColumn()
id: ObjectId;
```

to this

```
@ObjectIdColumn()
_id: ObjectId;
```

and after generating new records, query like this

```
const postId = 'xxx';

const postRepository = connection.getMongoRepository(Post);
const post = await postRepository.findOne(postId);
```